# Access control on S3 objects for a group of cognito identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-control, amazon-cognito

We are writing an image sharing app using Cognito for identity management and S3 for object storage. When a user uploads an image, they can set the image permission to private, public or friend, where friend is a set of the app users.

Setting the access control on an S3 object seems clear when it’s simply private or public (e.g. using Canned ACLs). However, it is unclear how we can make an object be accessible to only a group of Cognito identities.

We have looked at tags, meta data and bucket policies. Tags and bucket policies are only bucket level and we want them object-level. Meta data can be set for individual objects, however I don’t think we can set a meta data as a condition inside a Cognito Role. Is there a way we can do this?

It seems the crux of the problem is that there is no way we can create sub groups of cognito identities and assign  these groups access to a resource.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

tl;dr How can we make an S3 object be accessible to only a group of cognito identities?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Cognito does not have a way to allow access to an arbitrary, fluid group of ids. The only way that a group of ids can be given access, as of now, is what was described in [this blog](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies), which requires the ids to be hardcoded into the role:

```
"StringEquals": {
"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:12345678-dead-beef-cafe-123456790ab",
"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": [
        "us-east-1:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456790ab",
        "us-east-1:98765432-1234-1234-1243-123456790ab"
] }
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Just to be specific, the only way we can give group access to an S3 object is for IAM groups. Is that correct?

Comment: The only way to accomplish what you want through Cognito is through the IAM role (role and group are two different IAM entities) Cognito would assume. To do it in the dynamic way you describe, you would need to use some additional, independent mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: One possibility could be to use sync data with it. You could send a S3 signed url to some backend you have, then have this backend use your developer credentials to update the sync data for whatever group of friends a user has with that signed url. Private could be kept with the creating user and public is configurable.